# Multi processing and cache duplicates

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, multiprocessing

I have a Django site that runs in multi-processing. And I have Memcahced through Python-memchached enabled. I understand that each process has its own memory.

I have a custom cache that loads a whole database table T and its related fields into memory efficiently, then recreates this whole data into a different format and keeps it in object F. Every time a user tries to add/delete/update the T table through Django, the site will first apply those changes into F. If the changes pass some criteria, it will then save it in the Django object and the database. If changes don’t pass the criteria, it rolls back F without touching Django object or the database.

I have placed F in the custom manager of the original table.

**Goal: one F to serve them all**

**Problem: each process has its own F. They are not consistent with each other. Initializing F is heavy and I’d like it to happen only once when the Django app is initialized. Then modifying F afterwards is cheap.**

**Question: Where should I put F? Does Memcahced have one copy of data from database? In that case can I put F (which is a python object) in the memcached and deal with it directly there? How can I define it somewhere that F will be initialized only once and all processes will have access to it?**

If it helps, here are more details:
F is a NetworkX graph.  Django: 1.4.3  Gunicorn: 0.17.0

Thanks a lot!

Eras

Comment: Maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681015/storing-subprocess-object-in-memory-using-global-singleton-instance